# lookup value from another column that matches with new column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Here is my setup. I have 4 columns. Column A will contain value "y" or empty. Column B will contain a names. Column C will contain the same names as in column B but in a different order. What I want to do is fill out column D will the corresponding value for the name in Column B.

Find the name in column B that matches with C1, find it's value in A, and fill this value into D1.

Comment: I know this has something to do with VLOOKUP but I'm still working out the formula.  I'll post it as an answer when I get it working.

Comment: @pnuts updated. Sorry, find the name in column B that matches with cell C1

Comment: WHAT? That's pretty silly, Microsoft.

Comment: Just checked it out. Even though the syntax of INDEX is more complicated, it makes a lot more sense to me than VLOOKUP. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Right! That's what I meant to say. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(C1,B:B,0))
```

copied down to suit.

Comment: I thought it had to use VLOOKUP, but I guess not. Nice solution. (upvote)

Answer (score 0):

Could also use =INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(C1,B:B,0),1)) and fill down.

Comment: Agreed but I had put the time into finding a solution so I posted it.